# htacces with two domains. Point domain1/folder to domain1/anotherfolder/

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns, typo3

I have a hotel with two domains. Now the customer want a redirect:

```
domain1.dk/folder/ [nothing should happen]
domain2.dk/folder/ -> domain1.dk/anotherfolder/
```

The two URL's above (domain1.dk/folder/, domain2.dk/folder/) does not exist in the navigation structure today.

I am not sure if htaccess is the way to go when there are more thant one domain and the subfolders should be trated differently.

BR. Anders

P.S.
site is build in TYPO3, it is an apache server and php as programming language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a soulution that is not using .htaccess - it is a bit of a TYPO3 specific workaround partly done by the extension for TYPO3 called real_url